# How to detect sine pattern in a signal or time-series data?

Tags: python, time-series, pattern-recognition

I need to detect sine patterns in time-series data. Data includes small oscillations and a few numbers of sine patterns. What I need is `[Start Time, End Time]` of sine pattern.

Please note that there is a timestamp (0.5 second) to get data. Therefore, data is not continuous.

I appreciate it if you introduce any algorithm. 
Also, if the algorithm is already implemented in a python library, please guide me.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean to say that you are sampling at 2 samples per second?

Comment: yes. Actually, input is a video file. Frames per second is 2. And the data is the head angle (pitch). I want to detect Nod body language from Pitch.

Comment: The requirements also seems very loose here... how many samples must fit the pattern before it's considered valid? I could take 1 point and say that it's a sinusoid. What restrictions are there on the shape of data for it to be considered valid? Does the amplitude need to be constant? The frequency?

Comment: I can set a threshold value for amplitude. For example -5 and + 5 degree (data is head angle upward or downward).
And to detect sinusoid, one apex and one valley is enough.     
If you have any suggestion to define sinusoid pattern, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You may try [FFT method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/fft.html) to find a sine frequency, then use [correlation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html) with the model signal to bind it with time domain. Also you could use [spectrogram analysis](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.spectrogram.html) to get picture of your signal in time-frequency (it should looks like a line in time with the beginning and the end).

For example four sines with different frequencies may looks like on the spectrogram:
[image: Sines on spectrogram sample]